# Import failure when calling Anaconda Python from Windows shell

Tags: python, cmd, anaconda

I want to call my Anaconda Python from the Windows shell. The goal is to eventually call it from MATLAB using a system call, so I have to use the plain Windows shell, and not the "Anaconda prompt".

I have a simple Python script that I want to run, but it doesn't get past the import statements:

```
> "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe" lhs.py
Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "lhs.py", line 8, in <module> 
    import numpy 
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 140, in <module> 
    from . import _distributor_init 
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\_distributor_init.py", line 34, in <module> 
    from . import _mklinit 
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

**EDIT**

I made a simplified Python script (`error.py`) containing only one line:

`import numpy`

I then call it as:

`"C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe" error.py`

Comment: are you using an anaconda environment usually? If yes, that might be the reason: if you just call `python.exe lhs.py`, you won't have the packages installed for that

Comment: But they are installed. The ImportError is coming from numpy's own init sequence.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue. Instead, the anacondy python executable tells me `ModuleNotFoundError` when I call it like you do (and works when using within conda env). Can you provide a way to reproduce?

Comment: Related: https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/10884 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## TL;DR

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\condabin\activate.bat YOURENVIRONMENTNAME && python N:\Temp\lhs.py
```

---

## Long Answer

There is a [similar issue](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/10884) reported on github. I found this by searching for the last few lines of your message. It is about this:

> ```
> File "C:\Users\hanna\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python_init.py",
> ```
>
> line 47, in
>       import numpy as np
>       File "C:\Users\hanna\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy_init_.py", line 140, in
>       from . import _distributor_init
>       File "C:\Users\hanna\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy_distributor_init.py",
>   line 34, in
>       from . import _mklinit

There, they link to a [conda troubleshooting page](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/troubleshooting.html#numpy-mkl-library-load-failed):
Error messages like

> Intel MKL FATAL ERROR: Cannot load mkl_intel_thread.dll
>
> **Cause**
>   NumPy is unable to load the correct MKL or Intel OpenMP runtime
>   libraries. This is almost always caused by one of two things:
>
> 1. The environment with NumPy has not been activated.
> 2. Another software vendor has installed MKL or Intel OpenMP
>      (libiomp5md.dll) files into the C:\Windows\System32 folder. These
>      files are being loaded before Anaconda's and they're not compatible.
>
> **If you are not activating your environments, start with doing that.**

---

So let us try this first:

```
C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\condabin\\activate.bat
conda run -n yourenvironment C:\\path\\to\\your\\pythonfile\\lhs.py
```

(Yes, from a normal cmd terminal)

If that seems to work, you should be able to chain the two commands using `&&`. My own example looks like this:

```
F:\Programme\Programme\Anaconda3\condabin\activate.bat && conda run -n textrecognition N:\Temp\temp.py
```

This can be simplified further to

```
F:\Programme\Programme\Anaconda3\condabin\activate.bat textrecognition && python N:\Temp\temp.py
```

---

In case of the problem being number two, you have the option to load conda things before `system32`. This is supported in anaconda starting the following versions:

> Python 2.7.15 build 14
>
> Python 3.6.8 build 7
>
> Python 3.7.2 build 8

To activate that, you need to set some environment variables to 1:

> Control environment variables:
>
> ```
> CONDA_DLL_SEARCH_MODIFICATION_ENABLE
>
> CONDA_DLL_SEARCH_MODIFICATION_DEBUG
>
> CONDA_DLL_SEARCH_MODIFICATION_NEVER_ADD_WINDOWS_DIRECTORY
>
> CONDA_DLL_SEARCH_MODIFICATION_NEVER_ADD_CWD
> ```
>
> To set variables on Windows, you may use either the CLI (Anaconda
>   Prompt, for example) or a Windows GUI.
>
> CLI:
>   https://superuser.com/questions/79612/setting-and-getting-windows-environment-variables-from-the-command-prompt/79614
>
> GUI:
>   http://www.dowdandassociates.com/blog/content/howto-set-an-environment-variable-in-windows-gui/
>
> These should be set to a value of 1 to enable them. For example, in an
>   anaconda prompt terminal:
>
> `set CONDA_DLL_SEARCH_MODIFICATION_ENABLE=1`

Comment: I'm out of my depth here. What's the effect of creating a new environment (```conda activate myenv```)? How do I choose a suitable name?

Comment: Re: "let us try this first" -- ```conda``` is not a recognized command at a regular cmd shell.

Comment: OK, this is weird. I ran ```activate.bat``` like you said. Then I did ```conda run lhs.py``` (omitting the environment arg). It opened ```lhs.py``` in my default text editor, instead of running it.

Comment: Uh.. okay lol. I guess try my latest edit on the start of my answer, which is without conda run

Comment: @Ilya Re: "What's the effect of creating a new environment?" I really recommend you learn more about that, but it's out of scope for this question. Basically, an environment contains the modules you use, so that you can have different versions and combinations for different programs. It's the main reason to use anaconda

Answer (score 0):

you need to activate your conda base in cmd before calling the script

```
call <path>\anaconda\Scripts\activate base
<path>\anaconda\python.exe <path>\scriptname.py
```